# If I lose my developer certificate how can I update my app in the Android Marketplace?

Tags: android, google-play

If I lose my developer certificate how can I update my app in the Android Marketplace? I want the new version to go out as an update not a new app.

Comment: Back up early. Back up often. Back up offsite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, you're screwed. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If the certificate you used is now gone, you can no longer update that app. Your only hope is to throw up a Hail Mary and contact the android market team to see if they can do anything for you.